# Hide N-menu panels

Tags: 3d-view, interface, add-on, panel

Eventually you'll end up with a bunch of addons installed, and they seemingly all add tabs/panels to right side of the 3d view (the panel that can be toggled open/closed with the <kbd>n</kbd> key).

I have ~13 panels now and they all are truncated down to a single letter. I only really want a few of them, but I don't want to completely disable the addons as they serve other purposes (not just the n-menu panel).

When right-clicking on any of the panels, there doesn't appear to be any way to hide the panels. Anyone know of any methods to remove unused panels without having to disable the addon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter UI there is a nice tool in Sidebar(N) > Tool > Workspace

When ticked Filter Addons, the unmarked addons no longer displayed in sidebar, but continue to work.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is (yet another one) add-on for that:

https://chippwalters.gumroad.com/l/simpletabs

Using it, you can consolidate tabs, so that the total number of them will be reduced.