# Is there a way to access N-Panel items without going through the N-Panel menu?

Tags: interface, add-on, panel

I have over a dozen add-ons that are accessed via the N-Panel. **Is there a way to access these add-ons without having to go through the N-Panel?**

Like a lot of Blender users, my N-Panel has become messy with too many add-ons taking up too little real estate. I've tried several N-Panel managers with varying degrees of success (the biggest problem is that they tend to mess up when it comes to add-ons that dynamically create panel menus, e.g., Blenderkit). It would be great if I could access these N-Panel menus without having to hunt and peck through the N-Panel. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11

Comment: You might check this Q&A too, you could hide some of the panels on some workspaces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248211/hide-n-menu-panels

Comment: @Luciano Thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware of Blender's built-in N-Panel filter. Beyond that, is there a way to access add-ons without having to deal with the N-Panel at all, maybe in the same way F3 allows you to search for Blender operators?

Comment: I don't think there is another way. It all depends on how the addon developer coded their addon. some operators in the addon may be accessible with F3. you just need to know how they named the operator.

Comment: Maybe the add-on [SIMPLE TABS](https://chippwalters.gumroad.com/l/simpletabs) will also help you to get a little more overview of the add-ons in the panel.

Comment: I like the name N-Panel. Maybe blender should formally call it that way in their documentation :)

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I used Simple Tabs for a while, but it can't handle Blenderkit's dynamically-generated panels. I'm currently using Horizon Panels, which I love! but it too can't handle dynamically-generated panels (the creator is currently working on a fix for this). I'm going to assume the answer to my question is no. :)